# += operator with String and casted char

Tags: java, string, casting, char

This may be a stupid question, but I found an interaction that I cannot understand. I think it has to do with how += works.

```
String temp = "";
temp += (char) 90 + 10;
System.out.println(temp); // "100"
temp = "" + (char) 90 + 10;
System.out.println(temp); // "Z10"
```

Z10 makes sense. 100 does not. I would think the second line would execute in one of two different ways to produce "Z10" or "d". Why does the casting seemingly get ignored?

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with `+=`. It is to do with how `+` works.

If either of the operands of `+` is of `String` type, `+` is the string concatenation operator; otherwise, it is numeric addition.

---

```
temp += (char) 90 + 10;
```

is the same as

```
temp += ((char) 90 + 10);
```

So the bracket is evaluated first, and then the `+=` is applied. Here, neither `(char) 90` nor `10` are `String`s, so `+` is numeric addition.

In order to do numeric addition, the two operands must be made compatible - this is called *binary numeric promotion*. If the operands are a `char` and an `int`, the `char` is widened to an `int`.

Hence `(char) 90` is immediately widened back to `90`; then the two `int`s can be added - yielding `100` - and then that can be appended to the `temp` String via `+=`.

---

On the other hand

```
temp += "" + (char) 90 + 10;
```

is the same as

```
temp += (("" + (char) 90) + 10);
```

So, it evaluates the inner-most brackets first.

Because `""` is a `String`, `"" + (char) 90` is string concatenation, resulting in the value `"Z"`. That's a `String` too; so `"Z" + 10` is also string concatenation, resulting in `"Z10"`.

Comment: Alright, thank you. So the binary numeric promotion thing that you refer to is like using an integer expression to initialize a double, right? This is just a special case of that where the + operator also changes based on what data type is used with it.

Comment: Using an integer to initialize a double is a [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2). But it's the same kind of idea: the compiler applies an automatic conversion to make a value compatible for a particular context.

Comment: Thanks--one last question. So if I understand correctly, `int foo = 100; String bar = "d"; foo == bar.charAt(0)` (unicode for 100 is 'd') should be true due to binary numeric promotion, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Assignment operators such as `+=` have the [lowest precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), and therefore `+=` is evaluated after `+`.

Hence, before the `+=` operator is evaluated, its 2 operands are evaluated. The first operand is `temp` and the second operand is `(char) 90 + 10`. `(char) 90 + 10` evaluates to `100` (two numeric operands, so `+` performs addition). Therefore `100` is concatenated to the empty `String` referenced by `temp`, resulting in the `String` "100".

On the other hand, in

```
temp = "" + (char) 90 + 10;
```

there are two `+` operators. Both have the same precedence, so they are evaluated from left to right.

- First `"" + (char) 90` performs concatenation of a `String` and a `char`, resulting in a `String` whose single character is the character matching the value 90 ("Z").
- Then the second `+` concatenates the `int` 10 to the `String` "Z", resulting in the `String` "Z10".

Answer (score 1):

Type casting has higher precedence than arithmetic operators.

`(char) 90 + 10` is evaluated as `((char) 90) + (10)`. The result of adding a `char` to an `int` is an `int`.

What you want instead is `(char) (90 + 10)`, i.e. cast the *result* of the addition to a `char`. Then it will be appended to the `String` as a `char`:

```
    String temp = "";
    temp += (char) (90 + 10);
    System.out.println(temp); // prints "d"
```